# rioxarray and vector data (including geocube)

Tags: rioxarray, geocube

I currently got some problem with rioxarray and geocube. I hope, this is the right place to ask.

I am using a vector file for the German state of Brandenburg, so it has a massive hole in it. The file only has this single shape in it. When I create a raster file with:

```py
    bb_raster = make_geocube(vector_data=bb_frame, resolution=(-60, 60), fill=-999)
```

But when I plot the data the plot is empty (white). But `np.all(bb_raster['id'].data == -999)` returns **False**

Because of its size it is much larger, than a tile from the sentinel satellites for example.

When I want to mask it with a sentinel-2 raster with:

```
scl = scl.rio.clip(bb_frame)
```

the

> ValueError: No valid geometry objects found for rasterize

is returned instead. But still it is "allowed" to ...rio.reproject() a sentinel-2 raster with the rasterized shape.
But when I plot these reprojected files, then all the plots are empty (white). Although valid data seems to be included the data xarray.DataArray.
An example:

```
    xarray.DataArray
    
        band: 1y: 4078x: 3894
    
        array([[[241, 241, 241, ...,   4,   4,   4],
                [241, 241, 241, ...,   4,   4,   4],
                [241, 241, 241, ...,   4,   4,   4],
                ...,
                [241, 241, 241, ..., 241, 241, 241],
                [241, 241, 241, ..., 241, 241, 241],
                [241, 241, 241, ..., 241, 241, 241]]], dtype=uint8)
    
        Coordinates:
            x
            (x)
            float64
            2.502e+05 2.502e+05 ... 4.838e+05
            y
            (y)
            float64
            5.935e+06 5.935e+06 ... 5.69e+06
            band
            (band)
            int32
            1
            spatial_ref
            ()
            int32
            0
        Attributes:
    
        scale_factor :
            1.0
        add_offset :
            0.0
        grid_mapping :
            spatial_ref
        _FillValue :
            241
```

What might be the cause and the solution to this weired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> But when I plot the data the plot is empty (white)

I have seen this quite a bit with matplotlib. I would recommend doing `rio.to_raster("file.tif")` and opening it in QGIS to view.

> scl = scl.rio.clip(bb_frame)

If you want to clip the sentinel raster, you cannot pass in the geodataframe directly, you need to convert it to a list of GeoJSON shapes.

See: https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/clip_geom.html#Clip-using-a-GeoDataFrame

Comment: Convert into: GeoJSON shapes: it seams to be enough to `scl = scl.rio.clip(bb_frame.geometry.values)`, is there a way to easily estimate the area of the non masked pixels?

Comment: You can count the number of cells with valid data and multiply that by the area of a cell.